# Is OpenSUSE 13.2 still upgradeable?

Tags: upgrade, opensuse

I've been running OpenSuSE 13.2 32-bit for ages because I'm lazy and I my private computer is only for causal browsing and media replay. I'm forced to upgrade now because more and more web sites (and recently, *all* plug-ins) have stopped working in Firefox.

To my chagrin, *all* official or private documentation about system upgrades are full of caveats of the type "you must do this one version at a time or risk incompatibilities" or "you must switch to 64-bit first, which is tricky and non-trivial" or "this will not work if you use the proprietary Nvidia driver" (which I do). Reading these texts I get the impression that a system upgrade will probably either fail or take longer than a new install.

Is it really that arduous to become up-to-date after five years? Or is there any better path to the holy grail of "I just want keep everything the way it runs now"?

Comment: I've upgraded an old Thinkpad T41 from OpenSUSE 13.2 to OpenSuSE Leap15.1 recently. That computer only does 32 bit, and the upgrade through ```zypper dup``` worked without problems. No nVidia hardware, though.

Comment: Perhaps you could also try switching to the open source `nouveau` driver instead of `nvidia` while upgrading.  The new version of the open source driver works great for me.